# A Message inside a Wordsquares Riddle

Tags: riddle, word-square

I want to give you (yes,you!) a message. However, in order to avoid our non-puzzling brothers from eavesdropping, I've decided to encrypt it inside this Wordsquares Riddle.

> It's correct, it's affirmative.
>   And it's indefinite in time, very long.
>   But in Korea, it's a great university.
>
> Cheating and deceptive.
>   Is it me? Sadly, it's wrong.
>   Just drop it on the table and let it be.
>
> It's not one, it's not three.
>   You might wonder why.
>   But "Look here!" said my Spanish pals.
>
> It comes to you, even when you're not ready.
>   An O.S., or an animal that don't fly.
>   Sound is used by docs, in hospitals.
>
> Crack one's name easily.
>   Born in Thailand, an English footballing guy.
>   A hearing tool, Hitler calls.

Did you get a lot of words? Sorry, but...

> ... my message is just one sentence long. And it's dangerous if anyone else gets the message.

Comment: So this is a 5x5 square this time?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well, I can't tell the size, really, because the title gives a big hint about what it should be. P.S. I usually call them Wordsquare Riddle.

Comment: Ah ok I think I get what you mean

Comment: That's a good puzzle, but some of the clues remind me of the [VW Polo "Small but tough" campaign](https://aotw-pd.s3.amazonaws.com/images/polo_crossword.jpg). `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message is:

> YOU GOT THE ANSWER

How:

> Each verse gives clues to a 3x3 word square. By taking the diagonals you get the above message.

It's correct, it's affirmative.
And it's indefinite in time, very long.
But in Korea, it's a great university.

> ```
> YES
> EON
> SNU
> ```
>
> = YOU
>
> ([SNU](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul_National_University) is Seoul National University.)

Cheating and deceptive.
Is it me? Sadly, it's wrong.
Just drop it on the table and let it be.

> Thanks to @MOehm:
>
> ```
> GYP
> YOU
> PUT
> ```
>
> = GOT

It's not one, it's not three.
You might wonder why.
But "Look here!" said my Spanish pals.

> ```
> TWO
> WHY
> OYE
> ```
>
> = THE
>
> Oye is Spanish for 'hey!' (Like 'Oi!')

It comes to you, even when you're not ready.
An O.S., or an animal that don't fly.
Sound is used by docs, in hospitals.

> Thanks Rubio
>
> ```
> AGE
> GNU
> EUS
> ```
>
> = ANS
>
> EUS is [Endoscopic Ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoscopic_ultrasound)

Crack one's name easily.
Born in Thailand, an English footballing guy.
A hearing tool, Hitler calls.

> ```
> WHO
> HEH
> OHR
> ```
>
> = WER
>
> OHR is German for ear, [Heh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kler_Heh) is a Sheffield United footballer born in a Thailand refugee camp.

Giving

> YOU GOT THE ANS WER

So the message is

> YOU GOT THE ANSWER. Can be very dangerous if someone else got it :P

Comment: I had first thought of sly, too, but I think gyp, you, put (got) works better.

Comment: @MOehm aaah thanks. I was trying  to work around 'you' for the second for ages but couldn't think of anything for the first. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if somebody else got this it would be *very* dangerous

Comment: Wow, didn't think it was that easy! How did you find that it's the diagonals? Have you got this kind of puzzle before?

Comment: @WilliamNathanael no, but I assumed it would have to be something  like that. I noticed it after I'd solved two squares - they said 'the' and 'you' so it was obvious from there. I like the idea though! Some of the clues could have been better but overall good puzzle

Answer (score 2):

The solutions are

> ... a set of 3x3 wordsquares, one per stanza, 5 in all.
>  From them we find a final solution of just a few words (4 in all) ...

1

> `Y E S`       It's correct, it's affirmative.
>  `E O N`       And it's indefinite in time, very long.
>  `S N U`       But in Korea, it's a great university.   ([Seoul National University](https://www.useoul.edu/))

2

> `G Y P`       Cheating and deceptive.
>  `Y O U`       Is it me? Sadly, it's wrong.
>  `P U T`       Just drop it on the table and let it be.

3

> `T W O`       It's not one, it's not three.
>  `W H Y`       You might wonder why.
>  `O Y E`       But "Look here!" said my Spanish pals.
>  <sub>("Oye" is Spanish for "Listen up!", to get one's attention, and is used as we would say "Look here!")</sub>

4

> `A G E`       It comes to you, even when you're not ready.
>  `G N U`       An O.S., or an animal that don't fly.    (GNU Hurd is an OS)
>  `E U S`       Sound is used by docs, in hospitals.    ([Endoscopic Ultrasound](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/endoscopic-ultrasound) imaging)

5

> `W H O`       Crack one's name easily.
>  `H E H`       Born in Thailand, an English footballing guy.    ([Kler Heh](http://footballchannel.asia/2015/08/08/post6116/7/))
>  `O H R`       A hearing tool, Hitler calls.    (German for "ear" - thanks @M Oehm)

Final answer is thus:

> **YOU GOT THE ANSWER**
>  obtained by reading the diagonals of the 3x3 wordsquares.

Solved independently of, and pretty much simultaneously with, Beastly Gerbil's equivalent answer.  Thanks @M Oehm for the German word for ear.

Comment: You're bottom one is broken

Comment: oops. thanks.  Got mine independently of yours, btw - I saw a new answer so i hit submit

Comment: I think I may have just solved it. I know the final answer anyway just unsure of one of the squares

Comment: Okay, I also had emu, but the gnu angle looks good - and in that case the last one is Who? (to crack the name) - Keh - Ohr (ear in German), although I wouldn't call an ear a "tool".

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know german.  That makes it make sense.

Comment: Yeah just got all that. I have German lessons so worked out OHR and then the last one had to be Who to make it fit